# When deployed 127.0.0.1:6667 ip information in Apache IoTDB, why did the connection still failed in intranet environment?

Tags: database, apache-iotdb, iotdb

In the intranet environment, server A and server B of Apache IoTDB can set up ping successfully. I deployed springboot on IoTDB server A, and deployed ip information as `127.0.0.1:6667` (stated on official user guide) on IoTDB server B. The confignodes and datanodes of IoTDB are also configured, but the connection between server A and IoTDB database in server B failed. What did I do wrong and how to solve this problem? After I change any configuration, do I need to restart the system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `dn_rpc_address` of Apache IoTDB on server B needs to be changed to your own ip address, not `127.0.0.1`. Since this ip cannot be modified after IoTDB system is started once, so after you change the ip, you need to clean the environment, stop the original ConfigNode and DataNode processes, and delete the data directory. Then you can restart the system again and be able to execute IoTDB on server B.